# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable in Tensorflow 2.5

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am performing reinforcement learning and need to train an actor and a critic neural network over a custom environment.  I have the following code for my networks and RL agent:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow.keras.losses as kls

class critic(tf.keras.Model):
    ## Critic NN
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu')
        self.v = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = None)

    def call(self, input_data):
        x = self.d1(input_data)
        v = self.v(x)
        return v
    
class actor(tf.keras.Model):
    ## Actor NN
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu')
        self.a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax')

    def call(self, input_data):
        x = self.d1(input_data)
        a = self.a(x)
        return a

class rlalgorithm:
    ## RL Agent that trains the above NNs based on data from environment
    def __init__(self, actions, learning_rate=0.1):
        ## Display name for graphing performance
        self.display_name="A2C"
        ## Root Mean Square Optimizer for minimizing A2C losses
        self.a_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        self.c_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        ## Initialize models
        self.actor = actor()
        self.critic = critic()
        ## Define training constants and variables
        learn_rate = tf.constant(learning_rate, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.reward = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.state = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(1, 4)), dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 4))
        self.next_state = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=(1, 4)), dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 4))
        self.action = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.float32)
        ## The graph that produces the advantage
        advantage = self.reward + learn_rate*self.critic(self.next_state) - self.critic(self.state)
        ## Graph that produces losses
        dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=self.actor(self.state), dtype=tf.float32)
        self.actor_loss = dist.log_prob(self.action)*advantage
        self.critic_loss = advantage**2

    def choose_action(self, state):
        ## Agent chooses action to proceed to next state
        prob = self.actor(tf.convert_to_tensor([state]))
        dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=prob, dtype=tf.float32)
        action = dist.sample()
        return int(action.numpy()[0])

    def learn(self, s, a, r, s_):
        ## Based on chosen action, learn from result

        ## Assign training variables for this state-action outcome
        self.reward = self.reward.assign(r)
        self.state = self.state.assign(tf.convert_to_tensor([s]))
        self.next_state = self.next_state.assign(tf.convert_to_tensor([s_]))
        self.action = self.action.assign(a)

        ## Generate the loss gradient for actor
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            actor_grad = tape.gradient(self.actor_loss, self.actor.trainable_variables)
            self.a_opt.apply_gradients(zip(actor_grad, self.actor.trainable_variables))

        ## Generate the loss gradient for critic
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            critic_grad = tape.gradient(self.critic_loss, self.critic.trainable_variables)
            self.c_opt.apply_gradients(zip(critic_grad, self.critic.trainable_variables))

        ## Environment uses this, not relevant to learning
        return s_, self.choose_action(s_)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['actor/dense/kernel:0', 'actor/dense/bias:0', 'actor/dense_1/kernel:0', 'actor/dense_1/bias:0'].
```

I have seen this question asked multiple times, but none of the previous solutions seem to work for my case.  Unfortunately, I cannot provide the environment that this agent runs on but the error is only contained within the above file.

I have read through the docs and tried a similar implementation using the optimizer minimize function, with the same results.

I suspect the issue is related to how the tensorflow graphs are defined, but am unsure of what exactly the problem is.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on my own.

What I didn't understand was the proper usage of tf.GradientTape.  Within the with block, I need to perform the operations that compute loss, so that the gradients can be found.

Here is the updated learn function, for anybody else' reference:

```
def learn(self, s, a, r, s_):
        ## Based on chosen action, learn from result
        ## Assign training variables for this state-action outcome
        self.reward = self.reward.assign(r)
        self.state = self.state.assign(tf.convert_to_tensor([s]))
        self.next_state = self.next_state.assign(tf.convert_to_tensor([s_]))
        self.action = self.action.assign(a)

        ## Generate the loss gradient for critic
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            advantage = self.reward + self.learn_rate*self.critic(self.next_state) - self.critic(self.state)
            critic_loss = advantage**2
            critic_grad = tape.gradient(critic_loss, self.critic.trainable_variables)
            self.c_opt.apply_gradients(zip(critic_grad, self.critic.trainable_variables))

        ## Generate the loss gradient for actor
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=self.actor(self.state), dtype=tf.float32)
            actor_loss = dist.log_prob(self.action)*self.advantage
            actor_grad = tape.gradient(actor_loss, self.actor.trainable_variables)
            self.a_opt.apply_gradients(zip(actor_grad, self.actor.trainable_variables))

        ## Environment uses this, not relevant to learning
        return s_, self.choose_action(s_)
```